# How do I optimize a MongoDB change stream?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have some mongodb queries that are returning 1000 results, when I look in the mongodb.com profiler it shows me this:

```
{
  "command": {
    "getMore": 8223354687588024000,
    "collection": "reservations",
    "batchSize": 1000,
    "lsid": {
      "id": {
        "$binary": {
          "base64": "n8eH91eURw+xpT6fNEPURQ==",
          "subType": "04"
        }
      }
    },
    "$clusterTime": {
      "clusterTime": {
        "$timestamp": {
          "t": 1659066401,
          "i": 542
        }
      },
      "signature": {
        "hash": {
          "$binary": {
            "base64": "PHh4eHh4eD4=",
            "subType": "00"
          }
        },
        "keyId": 7090947493382324000
      }
    },
    "$db": "superhosttools"
  },
  "originatingCommand": {
    "aggregate": "reservations",
    "pipeline": [
      {
        "$changeStream": {
          "fullDocument": "updateLookup"
        }
      }
    ],
    "cursor": {},
    "lsid": {
      "id": {
        "$binary": {
          "base64": "n8eH91eURw+xpT6fNEPURQ==",
          "subType": "04"
        }
      }
    },
    "$clusterTime": {
      "clusterTime": {
        "$timestamp": {
          "t": 1659064839,
          "i": 29
        }
      },
      "signature": {
        "hash": {
          "$binary": {
            "base64": "PHh4eHh4eD4=",
            "subType": "00"
          }
        },
        "keyId": 7090947493382324000
      }
    },
    "$db": "superhosttools"
  },
  "planSummary": [
    {
      "COLLSCAN": {}
    }
  ],
  "cursorid": 8223354687588024000,
  "keysExamined": 0,
  "docsExamined": 26879,
  "numYields": 210,
  "nreturned": 1000,
  "reslen": 15283228,
  "locks": {
    "ReplicationStateTransition": {
      "acquireCount": {
        "w": 2206
      }
    },
    "Global": {
      "acquireCount": {
        "r": 2206
      }
    },
    "Database": {
      "acquireCount": {
        "r": 2206
      }
    },
    "Collection": {
      "acquireCount": {
        "r": 1994
      }
    },
    "Mutex": {
      "acquireCount": {
        "r": 1996
      }
    },
    "oplog": {
      "acquireCount": {
        "r": 211
      }
    }
  },
  "storage": {
    "data": {
      "bytesRead": 2083760,
      "timeReadingMicros": 4772
    }
  },
  "protocol": "op_msg",
  "millis": 249,
  "v": "4.2.21"
}
```

This looks like the interesting part and we use change streams but I don’t know why we would get 1000 results:

```
    "pipeline": [
      {
        "$changeStream": {
          "fullDocument": "updateLookup"
        }
      }
    ],
```

I'm trying to optimize my mongodb server. Any help how to make this query more efficient is appreciated.

#### Update #1

I removed the `{"fullDocument": "updateLookup"}` parameter from my watch code which seemed to help but I'm I'm still get some similar queries returning 1000 documents:

```
    "aggregate": "reservations",
    "pipeline": [
      {
        "$changeStream": {
          "fullDocument": "default"
        }
      }
    ],
```

I'm using now using the following code to implement the change stream:

```
Reservation.watch([]).on("change", async (change: ChangeEvent<ReservationDocument>) => {...});
```

I'm not wondering if I should add a query to the `.watch([])` call to limit the number of documents?  What is considered best practices with change streams?

Comment: Is there only one occurrence of this or it is happening with close intervals?

Comment: An aggregate or find query returns a cursor. The documents are read in batches from this resulting cursor. The batch size is configurable and it looks like the present size is 1000. Also see: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/database-profiler/#mongodb-data-system.profile.op

Comment: @AmoghSarpotdar there are multiple.

Comment: @prasad_ are you saying it’s a `.find()` or `.aggregate()` query? Why is there no query parameter?  Is it being called without one? `.find({})`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don’t know why we would get 1000 results

Your cursors are being limited to 1000 results by [`batchSize`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.batchSize/). You can add `batchSize` as an optional parameter to the [`collection.watch()`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.watch/) call:

```
db.collection.watch([], {batchSize: <number>})
```

Since change streams are cursors, you can also apply a [`limit()`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/#cursor.limit--) to the cursor before retrieving documents:

```
db.collection.watch(pipeline, options).limit(<number>)
```

> Should I add a query to the `.watch([])` call to limit the number of documents? What is considered best practices with change streams?

You may want to filter it to only events you care about (see below). Barring that, the defaults are the best practice.

> I'm trying to optimize my mongodb server. Any help how to make this query more efficient is appreciated.

The question of [optimizing a MongoDB server](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/optimize-query-performance-with-indexes-and-projections/) in general is too board for this question, so I'll keep this response limited to change streams as that appears to be the specific use case OP is asking about.

Starting in MongoDB 5.1, change streams are optimized, providing more efficient resource utilization and faster execution of some aggregation pipeline stages. If you aren't already on a newer version, updating to 5.1 or newer will provide a performance boost.

You can look at the [Change Streams Production Recommendations](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/administration/change-streams-production-recommendations/) to see if you are complying with the official Mongo advice. The only relevant section to performance is this one:

> If a sharded collection has high levels of activity, the `mongos` may not be able to keep up with the changes across all of the shards. Consider utilizing notification filters for these types of collections. For example, passing a `$match` pipeline configured to filter only insert operations.

So if you are using `collection.watch()` on a very active collection and you only need to act on certain changes, use [`$match`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) to filter down to just the changes you care about.

For example, if you only care about items authored by "dave":

```
db.collection.watch(
    [ { $match : { author : "dave" } } ]
);
```

## More considerations on batch size

As for your previous questions about batch size, reducing the batch size won't really have an effect on performance (with one exception noted below), so if performance is your only concern, you'll want to look elsewhere. From the [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.batchSize/#mongodb-method-cursor.batchSize):

> Specifies the number of documents to return in each batch of the response from the MongoDB instance. In most cases, modifying the batch size will not affect the user or the application, as `mongosh` and most drivers return results as if MongoDB returned a single batch.

There is one caveat, explained in great detail [here](https://www.alexbevi.com/blog/2022/03/02/performance-analysis-of-resuming-a-mongodb-change-stream/):

> If you’re using MongoDB Change Streams and filtering for events that occur infrequently (compared to other activity within the oplog) resuming the change stream may appear “sluggish” using the defaults. Consider specifying a custom `batchSize` based on your workload to potentially improve the time to returning the first event.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  The issue isn't that I want it to return more than 1000, I want it to return less.  Do you know if it is recommended to add a `pipeline` value to the `collection.watch([])` call?

Comment: @Dev01 I updated my answer with details on how to limit the batch size, and how to limit the cursor response.

Comment: I'm not on MongoDB 5.1 yet, I'll look into upgrading now, thanks for the advice.  I'm worried about limiting the batch size as I don't know why it's returning 1000 documents to begin with.  Is this normal and something I should not worry about optimizing?

Comment: @Dev01 I updated with more performance advice. You can add filters to `watch` if you have high activity levels.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at this part of your profiling output:

```
"originatingCommand": {
    "aggregate": "reservations",
    "pipeline": [
      {
        "$changeStream": {
          "fullDocument": "updateLookup"
        }
      }
    ],
    "cursor": {},
```

It is telling that, this query was triggered due to your aggregation pipeline.
Although you are using `change streams`, they internally implement a resumable
cursor based functionality itself. The only difference being, the `cursor`, calls the [`getMore`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/getMore/#mongodb-dbcommand-dbcmd.getMore) command `"getMore": 8223354687588024000,` to fetch data in batches, at periodic intervals. Your batch size being 1000.

Have a look Mongodb Community discussion, it should clear your [concern](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/change-stream-watch-cursor/1836).

Comment: Thank you for the help.  What can I do to reduce these large queries from the DB?  For example, if I remove the `{"fullDocument": "updateLookup"}` option will that remove these queries?

Comment: That depends on the usage, the option `{"fullDocument": "updateLookup"}`, basically configures the change stream to return the version of the document that is committed to majority of the nodes in a replica set. Documentation https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/changeStreams/#lookup-full-document-for-update-operations. If you are not using that info in anyway, then yes, removing the `change stream` from the `reservations` collection should do the trick for you.

Comment: Simply removing  `{"fullDocument": "updateLookup"}`, because the change stream cursor will be there, the query however might change

Comment: I removed `{"fullDocument": "updateLookup"}` as suggested and I think it helped but didn't fix the issue.  I updated my question with the queries I'm seeing now.  I wonder if I should be adding a query to the `.watch()` function?

Comment: I believe, that until we remove check streams, these queries will come. Depending on the change stream config, it will vary. Example: adding a pipeline to watch, will just add additional filters to the query, that's it. So, my recommendation to you is to ask this question in the MongoDB community. Explain your scenario, MongoDB version, and node driver version, because the cursor implementations vary with language drivers. That said if you are encountering downtime or performance constraints, then that will be the best bet. Or you can simply reduce the batch size.

Comment: You can also, start or resume change streams, on the basis of some specific events, using `startAfter` and `resumeAfter` tokens. It might reduce the query, but they will still be there. Please check out the relevant options here https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/changeStreams/#resume-a-change-stream

Comment: This might help as well https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/administration/change-streams-production-recommendations/

Comment: @CharchitKapoor I already linked the production recommendations in my answer above

Comment: Ohh ok, I didn't noticed